# how to store a sum of data in one column from mysql to one variable in java?

Tags: java, mysql

I need to get the sum of all the credit_balances and store it in one variable to use in my java program. The data type in MySQL is double for the credit balance. I keep getting a result of 0 for this code: Thank you in advance.

```
    try {
        double cdebts = 0;

        String rq3 = "select credit_balance from credit where user_id = '" + uid + "'";
        st3 = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs3 = st3.executeQuery(rq3);

        while ((rs3.next())) {
            cdebts = rs3.getDouble(1);
            totalcdebts += cdebts;
        }

    } // end try
    catch (Exception i) {
        System.out.print(i);
    } // end catch
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you? Do you get any results at all? Do you get valid doubles?

Comment: Better to do `select sum(credit_balance) ...` so less data has to be transferred from database to program.

Comment: Use "select sum(credit_balance)  as credit_bal_total from credit where user_id = '" + uid + "'";

Comment: I bet that code throws **exception**, which you print (somewhere) and then ignore, leaving `totalcdebts` unchanged.

Comment: i returns a value of 0, but it should return a value somewhere around 4700.

Comment: my debugger shows no exception thrown. I have only been using mysql for a couple of days and java for 3 months and I don't know how to set a variable from the database and have never used the sumation in this database.

Comment: When you step through the debugger on line at a time, did it reach the `while` loop? If no, then exception occurred. If yes, did it just step past the `while` loop body? If so, then query returned no rows. If it entered the loop, what is value assigned to `cdebts`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with that works.

try {

```
                         String rq3 = "select sum(credit_balance) from credit where user_id = '" + userid + "'";
                         st3 = conn.prepareStatement(rq3);
                         ResultSet rs3 = st3.executeQuery(rq3);

                         if(rs3.next()) {
                             String sum = rs3.getString(1);
                             totalcdebts = sum;
                             lblTotalCreditDebt_Label.setText(CCDebt + totalcdebts);
                         }
                                rs3.close();
                                st3.close();
                     }// end try 
                     catch(Exception i) {
                         System.out.print(i);
                     }//end catch
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, please don't generate your SQL queries in this way by passing in a variable into the query, this opens you up to a host of SQL Injection Attacks. Use PreparedStatements instead.

Next, as others have suggested, do the SUMation at the MySQL level;

```
String userID = "123";
String selectSQL = "SELECT SUM(credit_balance) AS TotalCreditBalance FROM credit WHERE user_id = ? ";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, userID);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
String totalCreditBalance = rs.getString("TotalCreditBalance");
```

Then do whatever conversions you want. Alternatively, use the relevant rs.getX to retrieve the specific data type you want, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html.

Updated answer with additional spoon feeding information to suit grumpy folk commenting... (ps. take note: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1)

Comment: Doesn't in any way address the problem posed in the question, i.e. why result is 0. Doesn't even show how to retrieve the summed value, and doesn't show good resource management. Your two advises are generally good, but should be comments to the question, not posted as an answer.

Comment: That is good advice, but after the query runs how do you set the results to a variable?